# Volt directory can't be written

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

The error I am getting is

```
Warning: Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt\Compiler::compileFile(../app/views/index/index.phtml.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Users/mattstephens/Sites/magpie/public/index.php on line 26 Phalcon Exception: Volt directory can't be written
```

I have declared the volt engine usage in my bootstrap like so

```
$view->registerEngines(array(
      '.phtml' => 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt'
    ));
```

The mention of line 26 in my code points to the application handle function shown below

```
echo $application->handle()->getContent();
```

Is this a permissions related thing or due to a missing directory?

Comment: Only thing i can see when comparing to other codes is /cache/volt isn't in my dir structure.

Comment: After those `chown` things you need to delete old `app/cache/*` files if there's any, otherwise it keeps the same error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you specify a different folder for Volt to compile its templates, the folder where the view file is located will be used to create the relevant compiled file.

You can change this behavior by setting the proper option when you register your service as such:

```
use \Phalcon\Mvc\View as PhView;
use \Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt as PhVolt;

...

public function initView($options = array())
{
    $config = $this->di['config'];
    $di     = $this->di;

    $this->di['volt'] = function ($view, $di) use ($config) {

        $volt = new PhVolt($view, $di);
        $volt->setOptions(
            array(
                'compiledPath'      => $config->app_volt->path,
                'compiledExtension' => $config->app_volt->extension,
                'compiledSeparator' => $config->app_volt->separator,
                'stat'              => (bool) $config->app_volt->stat,
            )
        );

        return $volt;
    };

    /**
     * Setup the view service
     */
    $this->di['view'] = function () use ($config, $di) {

        $view = new PhView();
        $view->setViewsDir($config->app_path->views);
        $view->registerEngines(array('.volt' => 'volt'));

        return $view;
    };
}
```

The `$config` will store all the information you need. By using the `compiledPath` you instruct Volt to compile the templates there and then serve them to the front end. That folder needs to be writeable for the user that runs your web server `www-data` or other and can be outside your public folder.

The file structure I usually use is:

```
app
    \controllers
    \models
    \views
public
    \js
    \css
    \img
var
    \volt
    \logs
    \config
    \cache
```

Answer (score 6):

Change volt file permission (Inside app/cache) to 777 .Its working fine

Comment: Changing a permission to 777 can be a bit dangerous. Isn't it possible to give the strictly necessary rights ?

Comment: Hi there, It only works for Linux based system. Hower, I'm getting the same error on Windows machine. Do you've any other suggestions other than assigning 777 to the cache folder (which is not apparently possible in Windows).

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to several of the other answers here, don't just willy-nilly set permissions to 0777 and pretend everything's okay, that's completely ridiculous.  Your server needs to write to the volt folder inside your cache directory.

**You might need to create the folder first.**
`sudo mkdir cache`, and `sudo mkdir cache/volt`. Then chown that folder with whatever is the username that your server runs.

*NOTE: Depending on your configuration, the `cache` folder might be located at the project root and not inside `app`.*

For example, if your server launches under the permissions of user named 'www-data' (which is most common), after creating the proper folder structure, the following command will fix your issue:
`sudo chown www-data:www-data -R cache`

Comment: just did        sudo chown www-data:www-data -R cache thats all

Answer (score 2):

I have just made "app/cache" folder with 777 permitions) It works))

Answer (score 1):

change the "app/cache" folder permission to 777.
in my mac i did like this.

1. navigate inside the app folder of our phalcon framework
2. [chmod ugo=rwx cache]
3. make sure the cache folder permission is 777 by typing [ls -l].

Answer (score 1):

You should change ownership of your project directory with chown command,

> `chown -R your_system_user:webserver_user yourproject/`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the app/cache and app/cache/volt with these commands worked for my project structure.

`chmod -R a+w app/cache
chmod -R a+w app/cache/volt`

Answer (score 0):

Just go to /project_name/store/app/config/config.php and change cacheDir from **'cacheDir'       => __DIR__ . '/../../app/cache/'** to **'cacheDir'       => __DIR__ . '/../../cache/'**.

Also, change its write permission to 777.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `baseUri` in the `config.php` is same as the installation directory

if the issue persist, tail nginx logs `tail -f /var/log/nginx/*.log`.

Also try use `sudo setenforce 0`. This worked for me.